# change text of class of a class

Tags: jquery, html

I found all the images that their src is not: "delete.png" and change their image to be "active.png":

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").attr({ 'src': 'active.png', 'alt': 'Active' });
```

now I'm trying to change the text of: "Active" to "Not Active".

```
<td class="TableTD">
<p style="display:inline;" class="yellow" title="<p class='myclass'
style='margin-top:0px;font- size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-
bottom:0px'>Active</p>">
<img alt="Active" src="active.png" class="sign"/>
</p></td>
```

The word `Active` is found here:

```
size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>**Active**< /p>">
```

I think I should do something like:

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest(p).title[.myclass] = "Not Active"
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest(p)
```

**Update:**

maybe something like:

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest('p').find("title.myclass").html('Not Active');
```

Comment: you want change the content of tag but you chaninig alt attribiute. More over your html code is not valid against standards

Comment: Why would you have HTML in the title tag?

Comment: why the hell would you want to put HTML in the title attribute ??? (Lol @adneo for having the exact same question at the same time)

Comment: I know it's bad, but this is my given code.. I don't want to change all of the code of my friends.. :/

Comment: if you were a real friend you would show them the error of their ways

Comment: You're right.. I am trying to change it. how can I change it please?

Comment: Maybe try 
`$(".myclass").html('Not Active');`

Comment: can't I do something like: $("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest('p').find("title.myclass").html('Not Active');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest("p").attr('title', function(pos, value){
   return value.replace(">Active<", ">Not Active<");
});
```

Comment: can't I do something like:

$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest('p').find("title.myclass").html('Not Active');

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the "title" attribute value, you are trying to reference it like an element, wich is not possible,

Answer (score 1):

There's no sensible way to change the HTML inside the `title` tag since that's just plain text to the browser. I'd reset the tag from scratch like

```
$("img.sign[src!='delete.png']").closest("p").attr('title', "<p class='myclass' style='margin-top:0px;font- size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px'>Active</p>");
```

Doing a text replacement like Edorka suggested is maybe a better idea.

You could also have the text somewhere (hidden) outside of the tag, change it there and then set the `title` attr to the `html()` of that hidden container. (I would not advise to do that.)

Both is a bit hacky, but that's the price for putting HTML into a `title` tag I guess.